# Custom shortcode to obtain coupon code and amount of Woocommerce Smart Coupon

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm using YayMail plugin to customize my Woocommerce emails (Woocommerce processing Order Email in my case), additionally I'm using Woocommerce Smart Coupons (By StorApps) to sell gift cards in the store, therefore, a unique coupon code is generated for each order if the user bought a gift card. Although the coupon can be shown in the email with the hook `woocommerce_email_after_order_table` it renders the coupon with a lot of information I don't want, my intention is to do a custom shortcode to insert it in the email template using YayMail builder, this to render only the coupon code and another shortcode for the coupon amount.

My knowledge on this is not very good, I have this so far:

```
global $woocommerce_smart_coupon;

$coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );

$order = ( ! empty( $order_id ) ) ? wc_get_order( $order_id ) : null;

if ( $woocommerce_smart_coupon->is_wc_gte_30() ) {
    if ( ! is_object( $coupon ) || ! is_callable( array( $coupon, 'get_id' ) ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $coupon_id = $coupon->get_id();
    if ( empty( $coupon_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $coupon_code      = $coupon->get_code();
} else {
    $coupon_id        = ( ! empty( $coupon->id ) ) ? $coupon->id : 0;
    $coupon_code      = ( ! empty( $coupon->code ) ) ? $coupon->code : '';
}

$coupon_amount = $woocommerce_smart_coupon->get_amount( $coupon, true, $order );

function get_coupon_code( $coupon_code ) {
    return $coupon_code;
}

function get_coupon_amount( $coupon_amount ) {
    return $coupon_amount;
}

add_shortcode('my_woo_coupon_code', 'get_coupon_code');
add_shortcode('my_woo_coupon_amount', 'get_coupon_amount');
```

Is not working yet. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's not how shortcodes work. Your functions will not get a $coupon_code or a $coupon_amount passed as parameters. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/#parameters: _"Every shortcode callback is passed three parameters by default, including an array of attributes ($atts), the shortcode content or null if not set ($content), and finally the shortcode tag itself ($shortcode_tag), in that order."_